# How can I get or obtain Pearlescent weapons?

Tags: borderlands-2

A big update hit Borderlands 2 today, and along with adding a new level cap with a bunch of bug/exploit fixes, it added the new "Pearlescent" weapons.

Where can I get these weapons? Are these available in vending machines? Do they drop from only specific enemies? What are the drop rates of Pearlescent weapons?

Comment: Just so you know, I've gotten a lot of these and haven't found one that i like better than legendary weapons.

Comment: That's the point, they're not "god tier", but they have some pretty nice upgrades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearlescent weapons are back, indeed. They are said do drop from enemies with the prefix 'Badass'. Probably would help to be in TVH or UTVH and have the Vault Hunter's relic. So, in closing, attack badass

EDIT - You cant get them in vending machines like you can get legendaries in Torgue's machines. Drop rates would be low, low like legendary or E-Tech. Hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

Not very low considering i have 8 now, but Legendary loot midgets have the highest chance of dropping them.